# printed dataframe, not the same when df.to_pickle. Values become NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pickle, nan

So I have a dictionary of dataframes  `stocks`
I call upon a stock's dataframe, by inserting a stock's ticker like this

`stocks['OPK']`  which calls up the stock 'OPK'
and the output is:

```
stocks['OPK']
            Open  High   Low  Close      Volume  Adj Close  
Date                                                                     
2010-01-04  1.80  1.97  1.76   1.95    234500.0       1.95          
2010-01-05  1.64  1.95  1.64   1.93    135800.0       1.93     
2010-01-06  1.90  1.92  1.77   1.79    546600.0       1.79   -  
2010-01-07  1.79  1.94  1.76   1.92    138700.0       1.92
```

EDIT: I've added the code to build the same Panel I'm playing around with, so those that are trying to tackle my problem, won't have a problem testing their ideas.

```
Here is the code to get the Panel (for reproducibility)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import re



startDate = '2010-01-01'
endDate = '2016-09-07'  
stocks_query = ['AAPL','OPK']


stocks = web.DataReader(stocks_query, data_source='yahoo',
          start=startDate, end=endDate)
stocks = stocks.swapaxes('items','minor_axis')`
```

Leading to an output of

```
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 1682 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: AAPL to OPK
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2016-09-07 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to Adj Close
```

I'm adding custom columns via a function then saving it to a pickle. After adding the columns, when I print the dataframe, I see no problems. However, when I save it to a pickle and load it, two of six newly created columns end up with missing values. I want to be able to saw it to a pickle so I don't have to keep recreating the columns. But I also wanted to do via a function, because I'm hoping to automate the creation of the columns.

Here is my code (for conciseness, I'm removed some parts):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import re

startDate = '2010-01-01'
endDate = dt.date.today()
stocks_query = ('AAPL','OPK')
source = 'yahoo'
columns =['Open', 'High', 'Low'......'p_changed']


def load_data(stocks_query, data_source, start, end):


    file_extension = '_'.join(stocks_query)

    stocks = pd.read_pickle('C:\\Users\Moondra\MachineLearning\\Stock_Market_Predictor-master\{}.pkl'. \
                             format(file_extension))
    try:
        stocks[stocks_query[0]]['log return']    #this checks if the customized
                                                    columns have been added

   except KeyError:
        print('There was an error, so we adding the columns')
        stocks =new_columns(stocks, columns)  #calls the function to add the columns
        stocks.to_pickle('C:\\Users\Moondra\MachineLearning\Stock_Market_Predictor-master\{}.pkl'.format\
                     (file_extension))  # saves to a pickle file
  return stocks



def new_columns(stocks, columns):   #this is the function that adds new columns
    stocks =stocks.reindex_axis([columns], 'minor_axis')
    for i in stocks:
    stocks[i]['log_return'] = np.log(stocks[i]['Close']/(stocks[i]['Close'].shift(1)))
    stocks [i] ['close_open'] = (stocks[i].Open - stocks[i].Close.shift(1))

    stocks[i]['30_Avg_Vol'] = stocks[i] ['Volume'].rolling(min_periods =15, window=30).mean()

    stocks[i]['changed'] = stocks[i]['close_open'] * stocks[i]['close_open'].shift(-1) < 0
    stocks[i]['p_changed'] = (stocks[i]['close_open'] + stocks[i]['close_open'].shift(-1) < stocks[i]['close_open'].shift(-1))\
                         &(stocks[i]['close_open']* stocks[i]['close_open'].shift(-1) < 0)


    return (stocks)
```

The problem I'm having is with the last two columns.
After running the code and typing `stocks['OPK']`, I have no problems. 
I see that all the columns have been added as well as their values.
The last columns are a little different because they return boolean values, but there are no anomalies.

Here is how my output looks (no mistakes):

```
Date                  changed p_changed                  
2010-01-04            False     False  
2010-01-05            False     False  
2010-01-06            False     False  
2010-01-07            False     False  
2010-01-08            False     False  
2010-01-11            True     False  
2010-01-12            False     False  
2010-01-13            False     False
```

However, when I load the pickle, (notice that in the `load_data` function, I'm saving it a pickle, right after adding the columns) and input stock['OPK'], the last two columns are presenting only NAN values.

```
                     changed  p_changed  
Date                                                        
2010-01-04           NaN           NaN        
2010-01-05           NaN           NaN       
2010-01-06           NaN           NaN      
2010-01-07           NaN           NaN
```

Not sure why this is happening.  The other columns that I'm adding, `log_returns`, etc  have no errors. It's only the last two columns, which are boolean values.
I'm suspecting it's something with that.

edit: I tried saving to the pickle, outside of the function as well. But this strange "Nan" output still remains the same.

Comment: My question would be, why are you pickling? Using the hdf5 standard, for example, or a database such as `sqlite` would be a generally more convenient and faster solution.

Comment: I just followed what I saw on tutorials and it seems most people, recommended `pickling` to save/load that you plan to reuse later. I was under the impression `pickling` is widely used.

Comment: I played around with the HDF5 format in Pandas ( store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5') and for some reason, I'm getting the same exact problem.

Comment: thanks for trying the other stuff too. So I guess the issue isn't due to pickling. As a side note, you're correct, pickling is widely used but for data storage, `hdf5` and `sqlite` are more portable. Pickling only works for Python, whereas `hdf5` and `sqlite` work for almost any widely used language.

Comment: Is your `new_columns` function returning the `DataFrame` `stocks`? I have a feeling that although the columns are created within the function, due to the way `Pandas` works with memory, it isn't storing the new values in the correct environment. Moreover, would you please fix the spacing and indentations of your functions?

Comment: also, in your loop, `for i in stocks:` are you trying to loop through the columns or the rows? It seems that it loops through the columns.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The` new_columns` function is returning the dataframe(actually Panel) `Stocks`.  When I type  `Stocks` in 'idle` I get an output of stocks that is correct. So that must mean the function is working.

Comment: As for your second question, for i in stocks is for each item in a panel. 
Remember I"m dealing with a bunch dataframes within a panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate, here's a workaround. the `Pandas Panel` is more of a hassle than a facilitator.

Use this code to convert your `stocks` data into a normal multi-indexed Pandas dataframe and watch things work.

```
#use this to convert your Panel into multi-indexed pd.DataFrame
stocks_df = pd.concat([stocks[item] for item in  stocks.items],keys = stocks.items)

#a new_columns function (note that it's different from yours)
def new_columns(df):   #this is the function that adds new columns
        df.loc[:,'log_return'] = np.log(df['Close']/(df['Close'].shift(1)))
        df.loc[:,'close_open'] = (df.Open - df.Close.shift(1))

        df.loc[:,'30_Avg_Vol'] = df.loc[:,'Volume'].rolling(min_periods =15, window=30).mean()

        df.loc[:,'changed'] = df['close_open'] * df['close_open'].shift(-1) < 0
        df.loc[:,'p_changed'] = (df['close_open'] + df['close_open'].shift(-1) < df['close_open'].shift(-1))  & (df['close_open']* df['close_open'].shift(-1) < 0)
        return(df)


#here's how you would run it:
stocks_df = stocks_df.groupby(level=0).apply(new_columns)

#now I pickle it:
stocks_df.to_pickle("pickled_df.pkl")

#here I retrieve it.           
stocks_read = pd.read_pickle("pickled_df.pkl")    

In [41]: stocks_read.head()
Out[41]:
                       Open        High         Low       Close       Volume  \
     Date
AAPL 2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  123432400.0
     2010-01-05  214.599998  215.589994  213.249994  214.379993  150476200.0
     2010-01-06  214.379993  215.230000  210.750004  210.969995  138040000.0
     2010-01-07  211.750000  212.000006  209.050005  210.580000  119282800.0
     2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005  111902700.0

                 Adj Close  log_return  close_open  30_Avg_Vol changed  \
     Date
AAPL 2010-01-04  27.727039         NaN         NaN         NaN   False
     2010-01-05  27.774976    0.001727    0.590000         NaN   False
     2010-01-06  27.333178   -0.016034    0.000000         NaN   False
     2010-01-07  27.282650   -0.001850    0.780005         NaN    True
     2010-01-08  27.464034    0.006626   -0.280006         NaN    True

                p_changed
     Date
AAPL 2010-01-04     False
     2010-01-05     False
     2010-01-06     False
     2010-01-07     False
     2010-01-08      True
```

See, if you don't use Panel then things work like a charm.

Comment: I actually have return (stocks) in my original code, I must have careless left out the last line from the `new_columns` function when transfering the code to StackOverflow. Sorry about that. I will retest and make sure.

Comment: Just rechecked. I do have return (stocks) so that's not the problem. The first time I ran the code, I didn't have any of the extra columns, so the function must be outputting correctly (or else when I load from pickle, I wouldn't have any of the new columns). It seems to be only the last two columns are not being outputted correctly.

Comment: @moondra, does the above code do what you want it to do?

Comment: Also, in your example output, the dataframe seems single-indexed by the date, what is the second layer? Instead of looping, I would recommend using the `groupby` functionality to run with `new_column` function for each outer leveled index.

Comment: @moondra, I added the groupby so that the code applies to a panel dataset to the bottom of the example. I tried to pickle it and read it and things works. However, please do note that your example still suggests single-indexed dataset

Comment: I will check out your code soon. I have to eat some lunch first. I'm going to edit my code to include how I made my panel.  I should have done that first. This way you can easily make the panel that I'm working with.

Comment: @moondra, I fixed the code to work with your `stocks` DataFrame. I basically just convert your object to a normal `DataFrame` and then apply your function (without the loop) using Pandas `groupby`

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up in a few things yesterday. But I will have time to play around with the code. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi, I'm playing around with you code a bit. I'm  not too familar with multi-indexing, so how can I slice the dataframe to pull out of the info of only one stock, say 'OPK' which is the second stock.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Everything seems to be working. Thank you so much. 
I will have to get used to using multi_indexing now instead of Panels, since Panels seems buggy.

Comment: @moondra, in Multi-indexing, it's the same as indexing. So for example, to pull put 'OPK' you can do `stocks_df.loc['OPK',:]` just as in standard indexing. For operational use though `groupby` is your best friend, since  df.groupby(level=0).get_group('OPK')` also returns you the subset BUT you can also `.apply` instead of `get_group` to apply your functions to the subset